# nodejs send list of all clients fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

js.
Currently I have done several tests successfully

- Hello world
- server-client communication with events
- many rooms

But i can't send the client, to the clients, i use **socket.io**

**The reason I want to do this, is to have a list of current clients**

EDIT:

I need to store information for each user in server side

---

i try use

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.listen(9876);
socket.on('connection', function(client) {

client.join('room');
console.log('new client ' + client.toString());

client.in('room').emit('list', client ); //<-- Error here

client.on('message', function(event) {
    console.log('client message! ', event);
    client.send(event);
});

client.on('chat', function(data) {

    client.broadcast.in('room').emit('LDS', data);
    client.in('room').emit('LDS', data);
});

client.on('disconnect', function() {

    console.log('out');
});
});
```

but throws this error

```
connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method

C:\Repos\InWeb\NO\node_modules\socket.io\lib\parser.js:75
  data = JSON.stringify(ev);
              ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at Object.stringify (native)
```

The original idea is send a list of clients, like this

```
var listClients;

socket.on('connection', function(client) {

client.join('room');

listClients.push(client);

client.in('room').emit('list', listClients); //<-- But throws same error
```

I guess that the error is given by the client context

I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You send whole object client, you should use something like this

[Socket.io Connected User Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275667/socket-io-connected-user-count)

or create array with name and id and send array not whole node object.