# express.io and rooms - can i get a count of people in the room?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Express.io obviously combines socket.io and express for node.js.  I'm trying however to find a way to get the # of sockets currently in a room and I can't find the right way to do it.

The code i've tried:

```
app.io.room('room').broadcast.length > 0
```

at first i thought this was the answer, but it turns out it just gives me the length of all sockets (at least i think that's what it's giving me).

or

```
app.io.socket.sockets.clients('room')
```

sockets doesn't exist on socket.  I tried this one based off of the way to do it with socket.io alone.

Looking at :
[getting how many people are in a chat room in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352549/getting-how-many-people-are-in-a-chat-room-in-socket-io)

It seems like it is easy to do with socket.io, I just can't seem to find it in express.io

Edit:

I've tried:

```
console.log(app.io.sockets.in(room).length);
console.log(express.io.sockets.in(room).length);
```

first one = undefined

second one = error (Cannot call method 'in' of undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
app.io.sockets.clients('room').length
```