# How to get room's clients list in socket.io 1.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I can get room's clients list with this code in socket.io 0.9.

```
io.sockets.clients(roomName)
```

How can I do this in socket.io 1.0?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352549/getting-how-many-people-are-in-a-chat-room-in-socket-io#24425207

Answer (score 36):

**Consider this rather more complete answer linked in a comment above on the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425207/1449799**

---

The clients in a room can be found at

```
io.nsps[yourNamespace].adapter.rooms[roomName]
```

This is an associative array with keys that are socket ids. In our case, we wanted to know the number of clients in a room, so we did `Object.keys(io.nsps[yourNamespace].adapter.rooms[roomName]).length`

In case you haven't seen/used namespaces (like this guy[me]), you can learn about them here http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ **(importantly: the default namespace is '/')**

Updated (esp. for @Zettam):

checkout this repo to see this working: https://github.com/thegreatmichael/socket-io-clients

Comment: Am I "this guy" ? ^^ Also, the default namespace is "/" or "".

Comment: @nha sorry, no, *I'm* "this guy"

Comment: @Michael I see :) To be honest it could have been me as well, I never really used namespaces (except for testing).

Comment: @Zettam yes. I updated the answer with a link to an example in github. See if that one works for you.

Answer (score 11):

Using [@ryan_Hdot link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23876398/1327651), I made a small temporary function in my code, which avoids maintaining a patch. Here it is :

```
function getClient(roomId) {
  var res = [],
      room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId];
  if (room) {
    for (var id in room) {
      res.push(io.sockets.adapter.nsp.connected[id]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

If using a namespace :

```
function getClient (ns, id) {
  return io.nsps[ns].adapter.rooms[id]
}
```

Which I use as a temporary fix for `io.sockets.clients(roomId)` which becomes `findClientsSocketByRoomId(roomId)`.

**EDIT :**

Most of the time it is worth considering avoiding using this method if possible.

What I do now is that I usually put a client in it's own room (ie. in a room whose name is it's clientID). I found the code more readable that way, and I don't have to rely on this workaround anymore.

Also, I haven't tested this with a Redis adapter.

If you have to, also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients) if you are using namespaces.

Answer (score 7):

For those of you using namespaces I made a function too that can handle different namespaces. It's quite the same as the answer of nha.

```js
function get_users_by_room(nsp, room) {
  var users = []
  for (var id in io.of(nsp).adapter.rooms[room]) {
    users.push(io.of(nsp).adapter.nsp.connected[id]);
  };
  return users;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

As of at least 1.4.5 nha’s method doesn’t work anymore either, and there is still no public api for getting clients in a room.  Here is what works for me.

`io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId]` returns an object that has two properties, sockets, and length.  The first is another object that has socketId’s for keys, and boolean’s as the values:

```
Room {
   sockets: 
   { '/#vQh0q0gVKgtLGIQGAAAB': true,
     '/#p9Z7l6UeYwhBQkdoAAAD': true },
   length: 2 }
```

So my code to get clients looks like this:

```
var sioRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId];
if( sioRoom ) { 
  Object.keys(sioRoom.sockets).forEach( function(socketId){
    console.log("sioRoom client socket Id: " + socketId );
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your trick. Your answer is now the real answer with up to date socket.io.

Answer (score 5):

You can see [this github pull request](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/pull/1428) for discussion on the topic, however, it seems as though that functionality has been stripped from the 1.0 pre release candidate for SocketIO.