# (number of) clients connected to a room in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've been struggling to find an efficient way to get the number of clients conencted to a room in socket.io.
I've been advised to look into this thread:
[How to get room's clients list in socket.io 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858604/how-to-get-rooms-clients-list-in-socket-io-1-0) however none of the solutions currently work in this thread besides the one that checks for every single conencted socket and their rooms to be able to display a single room's cliens.

Therefore, I need to ask once more: what is the (urrently) most efficient way to get the (number of) clients in a room in socket.io?

Comment: Can't you keep a count when a new user connects? And handle it appropriately when some user disconnects. It works, any issues with it?

Comment: @aravind I can of course handle this manually in many ways, but I would love to learn about the most optimal way (currently) to handle this. Since socket.io does not have a full and up to date documentation/api anywhere, it's the best to ask here.

Comment: Zettam: I used socket a long time ago, and I used the basic api only. :) I would like to know of a good way too!

Comment: I'd suggest make a simple app that sends a msg to everyone in a chat room and then just step through that code in the debugger and you will quickly see how socket.io keeps track of who is in a given chat room (since it has to know who's in every room in order to send to them all).  It's likely an array of connections somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`io.nsps[yourNamespace].adapter.rooms[roomName] // default namespace is '/'`

returns the object of clients with a boolean value or `undefined` if there is no clients. In the most of the cases you can get the length of this object with

`Object.keys(io.nsps[yourNamespace].adapter.rooms[roomName]).length`

but it only will work if there is at least one client connected, due to the undefined returned.

If you're not using any specific namespace, you can use `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName]` instead.

By default, when a client disconnects, it leaves the room, then this way has worked for me.