# socket.io How Can I Get "Socket object" list in room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

folks. So far, I have been searching "How can I get socket list in room". I was able to find a lot of results.

like this link. 
[How to get room's clients list in socket.io 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858604/how-to-get-rooms-clients-list-in-socket-io-1-0)
example, console.log(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms);

But, That answers can get the socket list in room **not "Object".**

I need socket object list of that into the socket in the room.

How can I get socket's object list in rooms. Please tell me solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`io.sockets.connected[SOCKET_ID_GOES_HERE]`

You can use `io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms` to find socket ids and then get the objects you need with the following code:

```
var sockets_in_room = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[ROOM_NAME_GOES_HERE]
var socket_objects = []

for (socketId in sockets_in_room) {
    socket_objects.push(io.sockets.connected[socketId])
}
```