# Count number of sockets in room with golang socketio package

Tags: go, socket.io

How do you count the number of sockets in a room in Golang. With socketio in nodejs it [appears you can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425207/288424):

```
io.of('/chat').sockets.length
```

How do you do the same with the [socketio library](http://godoc.org/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) for Golang?

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't. There is no method in the API that accepts a room and returns the number of sockets.

Post a feature request on the [project github page](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io).