# Error with Node.js & Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm following the tutorial provided here :
http://www.davidado.com/2013/12/10/node-js-for-user-alert-push-notifications/
The goal is to allow someone to send a message to another user.

Node is installed and works.  I also installed Socket.io.

When I run

```
node server.js
```

I have this error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/nodeapp/server.js:11:39)
```

The server.js (**server side**) is like this :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5120);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   socket.on('join_room', function (data) {
      if (typeof socket !== 'undefined') {
         // data.id should be set if user is logged in
         if (typeof data.id !== 'undefined' && data.id > 0) {
            // Check if socket is already in room
            var roomlist = io.sockets.clients(data.id); // returns Socket instances of all clients in the room
            var occupantSocket;
            if (typeof roomlist[0] !== 'undefined') {
               // Should only be one socket in a private room
               occupantSocket = roomlist[0];
            }
            if (socket !== occupantSocket) {
               // Socket hasn't joined before so join it now
               socket.join(data.id);
            }
         } else {
            // User ID isn't set so disconnect the socket
            socket.disconnect();
         }
      }
   });

   socket.on('send_msg', function (data) {
      if (typeof socket !== 'undefined') {
         if (typeof data.id_sendee !== 'undefined' && data.id_sendee > 0) {
            // Check if anyone is in the room before broadcasting
            var roomlist = io.sockets.clients(data.id_sendee);
            if (typeof roomlist[0] !== 'undefined') {
               // Push alerts aren't that critical so use volatile
               socket.broadcast.to(data.id_sendee).volatile.emit(
                  'newalert',
                  {sender: data.sender, msg: data.msg });
            }
         } else {
            socket.disconnect();
         }
      }
   });
});
console.log("Hello , just checking!");
```

**Line 11 is this one :**

> var roomlist = io.sockets.clients(data.id); // returns Socket
>   instances of all clients in the room

On the **client side**, the one receiving the message :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Node</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('http://IPAdressofMyServer:5120');
socket.emit('join_room', { id: 234 });

// Listen for 'newalert' event from node server at server.js
socket.on('newalert', function (data) {
alert( data.msg + ' from ' + data.sender );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch node server.js in my console, there is no error, but as soon as I refresh the client (with the code above), the error is triggered.

Any idea what the problem is ?
thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is not available as per 1.0.x version.

Please change your code based on this link: [getting how many people are in a chat room in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352549/getting-how-many-people-are-in-a-chat-room-in-socket-io)