# in nodejs when i enter two player in a room players disconnected

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, multiplayer

I want to create online tic tac with unity and nodejs that in it two player enter a room automatically when i enter two player in a room players disconnected!!
Note:each room has two player maximum

problems :

players  disconnected immediately after connect

and

io.sockets.clients().length  is not working

```
var io = require('socket.io')(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var shortid = require('shortid');
console.log('server started');
var usernames = {};
var ids = {};
var rooms = [];
var roomExist = false;//true if a room exist with one player in there
var lastRoom ;  // id of room  with one player
var numClients = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('addUser',function(username){
        socket.username = username;
    });
    socket.id = shortid.generate();
    socket.emit('yourId',socket.id);
    if (roomExist){//Player 2 joined
        socket.room = lastRoom;
        socket.join(lastRoom);
        roomExist = false;
        console.log('J client by id' ,socket.id,'by name',socket.username,'joined room',socket.room);
        console.log('number of clients is :',io.sockets.clients().length);
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('spawn');
        socket.on('move',function(data){
            console.log('client moved',JSON.stringify(data));
            socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('move',data);
        });
    }
    else {//Player 1 joined
        lastRoom = shortid.generate();
        rooms.push(lastRoom);
        socket.room = lastRoom;
        socket.join(lastRoom);
        roomExist = true;
        console.log('C client by id' ,socket.id,'by name',socket.username,'joined room',socket.room);
        console.log('number of clients is :',io.sockets.clients().length);
        socket.emit('wait'); // wait for player 2
        socket.on('move',function(data){
            console.log('client moved',JSON.stringify(data));
            socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('move',data);
        });
    }
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        console.log('client',socket.username,'disconnected');
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

Comment: whats the version of socket.io?

Comment: version of socket.io 1.4.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352549/getting-how-many-people-are-in-a-chat-room-in-socket-io#24425207

Comment: Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).length

Answer (score 0):

It's probably waaay late to answer but in socket.io 2.2.0 you should use:

```
io.sockets.clients.length
```

you had parenthesis after clients