# Node JS get data io.sockets.clients();

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

My English is a little bad sorry

I am trying to get all connected clients data

Sample;

```
var a_sockets           =   io.sockets.clients();

console.log(a_sockets);
```

Return ;

```
Namespace {
  name: '/',
  server:
   Server {
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] },
     parentNsps: Map {},
     _path: '/socket.io',
     _serveClient: true,
     parser:
      { protocol: 4,
        types: [Array],
        CONNECT: 0,
        DISCONNECT: 1,
        EVENT: 2,
        ACK: 3,
        ERROR: 4,
        BINARY_EVENT: 5,
        BINARY_ACK: 6,
        Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
        Decoder: [Function: Decoder] },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     _origins: '*:*',
     sockets: [Circular],
     eio:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [WebSocketServer],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     httpServer:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::9999',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5 },
     engine:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [WebSocketServer],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 } },
  sockets:
   { '71kTaZqD9WLFgyC0AAAA':
      Socket {
        nsp: [Circular],
        server: [Server],
        adapter: [Adapter],
        id: '71kTaZqD9WLFgyC0AAAA',
        client: [Client],
        conn: [Socket],
        rooms: {},
        acks: {},
        connected: true,
        disconnected: false,
        handshake: [Object],
        fns: [],
        flags: {},
        _rooms: [],
        userId:
         '8580af1b5f364c98a20a49185e018412642e92efb79421734881b53e1e1b18b6_t' } },
  connected:
   { '71kTaZqD9WLFgyC0AAAA':
      Socket {
        nsp: [Circular],
        server: [Server],
        adapter: [Adapter],
        id: '71kTaZqD9WLFgyC0AAAA',
        client: [Client],
        conn: [Socket],
        rooms: {},
        acks: {},
        connected: true,
        disconnected: false,
        handshake: [Object],
        fns: [],
        flags: {},
        _rooms: [],
        **userId:
         '8580af1b5f364c98a20a49185e018412642e92efb79421734881b53e1e1b18b6_t'** } },
  fns: [],
  ids: 0,
  rooms: [],
  flags: {},
  adapter:
   Adapter {
     nsp: [Circular],
     rooms: { '71kTaZqD9WLFgyC0AAAA': [Room] },
     sids: { '71kTaZqD9WLFgyC0AAAA': [Object] },
     encoder: Encoder {} },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1 }
```

just want to get userId data.

I want take it  [ Connected -> userId ]

So I can compare users
How can I solve this problem?
I apologize again for my english

Thanks.

I would be very happy if you could help me.
I wish you a good day

Comment: What is your socket.io version ? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352549/getting-how-many-people-are-in-a-chat-room-in-socket-io#24425207

Comment: Socket.IO Version : 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Short answer(assuming you are using version >=1.0):

```
var srvSockets = io.sockets.sockets;
Object.keys(srvSockets);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code is just giving the socket id I would like to get the value that I assigned to myself

https://imgur.com/JYpQapZ

Comment: For that you have to emit the value that you assign to the client on connection and subscribe to the emit event. That information isn't passed in the connection to the socket.