# Socket IO Rooms: Get list of clients in specific room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to display a list of clients in a specific room. I just want to show their username, and not their socket id.

This where I'm at:

```
socket.set('nickname', "Earl");  
socket.join('chatroom1');
console.log('User joined chat room 1);

var roster = io.sockets.clients('chatroom1');
for ( i in roster )
{
   console.log('Username: ' + roster[i]);   
}
```

Haven't had any luck getting it to list Socket IDs or anything. Would like it to return the nicknames however.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just a few things.

1. when you have the `socket` you can then set the properties like: `socket.nickname = 'Earl';` later to use the save property for example in a console log:
   `console.log(socket.nickname);`
2. you where missing a closing quote (') in your:

   `console.log('User joined chat room 1);`
3. Im not entirely sure about your loop.

Below is the amended code should help you out a bit, also be aware the loop i am using below is asynchronous and this may effect how you handle data transfers.

```
socket.nickname = 'Earl';
socket.join('chatroom1');

console.log('User joined chat room 1');
    
var roster = io.sockets.clients('chatroom1');
        
roster.forEach(function(client) {
    console.log('Username: ' + client.nickname);
});
```

to help you out more i would need to see all your code as this does not give me context.

Comment: Does "io.sockets.clients('chatroom1')" work in nodejs v1.0 & above?

Comment: Hello, I got an error in io.sockets.clients('roomname'), mysocket version is 2.2.0

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, it does not work for versions greater than socket.io 1.0.

Comment: this method does't exists anymore

Comment: method giving error : clients is not a function

Answer (score 77):

**In socket.IO 3.x**

[New to version 3.x is that connected is renamed to sockets and is now an ES6 Map on namespaces.](https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#Namespace-connected-is-renamed-to-Namespace-sockets-and-is-now-a-Map) On rooms sockets is an ES6 Set of client ids.

```
//this is an ES6 Set of all client ids in the room
const clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get('Room Name');

//to get the number of clients in this room
const numClients = clients ? clients.size : 0;

//to just emit the same event to all members of a room
io.to('Room Name').emit('new event', 'Updates');

for (const clientId of clients ) {

     //this is the socket of each client in the room.
     const clientSocket = io.sockets.sockets.get(clientId);

     //you can do whatever you need with this
     clientSocket.leave('Other Room')

}
```

**In socket.IO 1.x through 2.x**

Please refer the following answer:
[Get list of all clients in specific room](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028902/1766122). Replicated below with some modifications:

```
const clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['Room Name'].sockets;   

//to get the number of clients in this room
const numClients = clients ? Object.keys(clients).length : 0;

//to just emit the same event to all members of a room
io.to('Room Name').emit('new event', 'Updates');

for (const clientId in clients ) {

     //this is the socket of each client in the room.
     const clientSocket = io.sockets.connected[clientId];

     //you can do whatever you need with this
     clientSocket.leave('Other Room')
}
```

Comment: I need something > 1.0 but something you clearly indicate this doesn't work on 1.0 above, no reason for the downvote. Have a +1 to balance it out :p.

Answer (score 23):

**Instead of going deep in `socket/io` object , You can use simple and standard way :**

```
io.in(room_name).clients((err , clients) => {
    // clients will be array of socket ids , currently available in given room
});
```

For more detail **[DO READ](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-clients-callback)**

Comment: How can I use async and await with this?

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work with socket.IO v3 or newer.

Answer (score 16):

For v4 I used this method fetchSockets()

Example :

```
let roomUsers=await io.in(`room-id`).fetchSockets()
```

see documentation here :
https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/#Additional-utility-methods

Answer (score 5):

All the answers above and the one here [socket.io get rooms which socket is currently in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044660/socket-io-get-rooms-which-socket-is-currently-in) or here [Socket.IO - how do I get a list of connected sockets/clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients) were either incorrect or incomplete if you use 2.0.

1. In 2.0, `io.sockets.manager` and `io.sockets.clients` don't exist anymore.
2. Without using namespace, the following 3 parameters can all get sockets in a specific room.

   `socket.adapter.rooms;`

   `io.sockets.adapter.rooms;`

   `io.sockets.adapter.sids; // the socket.id array`
3. With namespace (I used "cs" here), `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` will give a quite confusing result and the result `socket.adapter.rooms` gives is correct:

```
/* socket.adapter.rooms give: */

{
  "/cs#v561bgPlss6ELZIZAAAB": {
    "sockets": {
      "/cs#v561bgPlss6ELZIZAAAB": true
    },
    "length": 1
  },
  "a room xxx": {"sockets": {
    "/cs#v561bgPlss6ELZIZAAAB": true
  },
  "length": 1
  }
}

/* io.sockets.adapter.rooms give: a sid without namespace*/

{
  "v561bgPlss6ELZIZAAAB": {
    "sockets": {
      "v561bgPlss6ELZIZAAAB": true
    }, "length": 1
  }
}
```

Note: the default room is this: "[Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room)."

I only tried memory adapter so far, have not tried redis-adapter.

Answer (score 4):

For Socket v.4 correct syntax would be:

```
const sockets = await io.in("room1").fetchSockets();
```

> https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespacefetchsockets

Answer (score 3):

For `socket.IO v3` there's a breaking change here:

> Namespace.clients() is renamed to Namespace.allSockets() and now returns a Promise.

BEFORE:

```
// all sockets in the "chat" namespace and in the "general" room
io.of("/chat").in("general").clients((error, clients) => {
  console.log(clients); // => [Anw2LatarvGVVXEIAAAD]
});
```

Now (v3):

```
// all sockets in the "chat" namespace and in the "general" room
const ids = await io.of("/chat").in("general").allSockets();
```

[Source](https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#Namespace-clients-is-renamed-to-Namespace-allSockets-and-now-returns-a-Promise)

In case you're not so familiar with socket.IO, it might be good to know that instead of `io.of("/chat")` you can write `io` to use the default namespace.

Comment: This also works in Socket.IO v4. To be precise, the example code above returns a Set of socket IDs, not the actual Socket objects. `io.of('/').sockets` can be used to get a Map of Socket instances connected to a namespace so `io.of('/').sockets.get(socketId)` gets the Socket instance matching the id.

Answer (score 3):

**In socket.IO 4.x**

```
const getConnectedUserIdList = async () => {
  let connectedUsers = [];
  let roomUsers = await io.in(`members`).fetchSockets();
  roomUsers.forEach((obj) => {
    connectedUsers.push(obj.request.user.id);
  });
  return connectedUsers;
};
```

Comment: with v4.7.2 and above, it is now _obj.id_

Answer (score 2):

socket.io ^ 2.0

```
function getRoomClients(room) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    io.of('/').in(room).clients((error, clients) => {
      resolve(clients);
    });
  });
}

...
const clients = await getRoomClients('hello-world');
console.log(clients);
```

Output

```
[ '9L47TWua75nkL_0qAAAA',
'tVDBzLjhPRNdgkZdAAAB',
'fHjm2kxKWjh0wUAKAAAC' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

From **Socket.io v3**, `rooms` is now a protected property of `Adapter` so you won't be able to access it via `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`.

Instead use:

```
const clientsInRoom = await io.in(roomName).allSockets()
```

OR for multiple rooms

```
const clientsInRooms = await io.sockets.adapter.sockets(new Set([roomName, roomName2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

For Socket.io greater than v1.0 and node v6.0+ use the following code:

```
function getSockets(room) { // will return all sockets with room name
  return Object.entries(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room] === undefined ?
  {} : io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room].sockets )
    .filter(([id, status]) => status) // get only status = true sockets 
    .map(([id]) => io.sockets.connected[id])
}
```

If you want to emit something to them , use this :

```
getSockets('room name').forEach(socket => socket.emit('event name', data))
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for

- socket.io : "3.0.4"
- socket.io-redis : "6.0.1"

import these first

```js
const redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

```js
socket.on('create or join', function(room) {
    log('Received request to create or join room ' + room);

    //var clientsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    
    mapObject = io.sockets.adapter.rooms // return Map Js Object
    clientsInRoom = new Set(mapObject.get(room))
  
    var numClients = clientsInRoom ? clientsInRoom.size : 0;
    log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
```

https://socket.io/docs/v3/using-multiple-nodes/#The-Redis-adapter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get

Comment: Thanks, this is the only working solution as of August 2022 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just logged all sockets in a room to the console, you can do whatever you like with them...

```
const socketsInRoom = io.adapter.rooms[room_name];

    /*Collect all participants in room*/
    for(let participant in socketsInRoom){
        for(let socketId in socketsInRoom[participant]){
            console.log(socketId)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**socket.io ^2.2.0**

```js
const socket = io(url)

socket.on('connection', client => {
  socket.of('/').in("some_room_name").clients((err, clients) => {
    console.log(clients) // an array of socket ids
  })
})
```

Comment: How can I use async and await with this?

Comment: A trivial answer would be to wrap the whole thing in an async function and await the callbacks.  This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035243/with-socketio-is-it-possible-to-use-async-with-socket-on

Answer (score 0):

you can use the adapter method on io object like

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get("chatroom1")
```

this will return the list of connected clients in the particular room.
io.sockets.adapter.rooms this is a map off all clients connected to rooms with room name as keys and the connected clients are the values of the room key. map functions are applicable .

Answer (score 0):

Since I have found very little on how to get the rooms inside a specific namespace, here it is in case anyone is wondering :

`io.of(namespaceName).adapter.rooms;`

Answer (score 0):

```
let sockets = await io
              .of("/namespace")
              .in(ROOM_NAME)
              .allSockets();
```

you can get length of connected clients via

```
console.log(receiver.size);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can create an array object of user collection as

```
var users = {};
```

then on server side you can add it as new user when you connect

```
socket.on('new-user', function (username) {
    users[username] = username;
});
```

while displaying the users, you can loop the "users" object

On Client side

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('new-user', 'username');
});
```

Comment: seriously, you're gonna send the username from the client side instead of checking the cookies and stuff? isn't it extremely easily fakable?

Comment: I would recommend using the socket.handshake.query with middleware to authenticate, then store that token/username as a socket property to refer to from the server-side so it will just work.