# socket.io get rooms which socket is currently in

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to get rooms which socket is currently in, without calling

```
io.sockets.clients(roomName)
```

for every room name and looking for this socket in results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Socket.IO Room doc](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms#rooms-a-client-has-joined):

`io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]`

Answer (score 44):

In socket.io version 1+ the syntax is:

```
socket.rooms
```

Comment: `socket.rooms` showing up blank in 1.3.6 ... does this still work for you?

Comment: Returns `undefined`, version: 1.6.0.

Comment: for me, it returns a blank object `{}`, I'm using 2.3.0

Comment: I am using 2.3.0 too, but it seems that it works for me? Even if no `socket.join()` is called it would returned a channel that equals to the socket id. Maybe you are not calling this inside the connection function? Or your connection function is having the parameter other then `socket`?

Answer (score 13):

## Cross-compatible way

```js
var rooms = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id]);
// returns [socket.id, 'room-x'] or [socket.id, 'room-1', 'room-2', ..., 'room-x']
```

Answer (score 13):

### Update: Socket.io 3.0 Released

---

With `3.x` Socket.rooms is `Set` now, which means that values in the rooms **may only occur once**.

Structure example: `Set(4) {"<socket ID>", "room1", "room2", "room3"}`

```
io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.rooms); // Set { <socket.id> }
  socket.join("room1");
  console.log(socket.rooms); // Set { <socket.id>, "room1" }
});
```

To check for specific room:

```
socket.rooms.has("room1"); // true
```

More about Set and available methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Migration Docs: https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/

Answer (score 4):

When using a *non-default adapter*, such as socket.io-redis, `socket.rooms` doesn't seem to do the trick. The way I managed to get the rooms for a specific client without looping was to use `io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id]`, which returns the rooms as an object.

```
{ 'R-ZRgSf7h4wfPatcAAAC': true, ROOM: true, ROOM_2: true }
```

Note that this doesn't list sockets on other processes, though!

socket.io v1.3.7, socket.io-redis 1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.7.3, `socket.rooms` contains `socket.id`, so remove it and get the list of rooms:

```
Object.keys(socket.rooms).filter(item => item!=socket.id);
```

In other version, you can print the `socket` and find the rooms.

Answer (score 2):

Being sure that socket is in only one room at a time, my solution was:

```
var currentRoom = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id]).filter(item => item!=socket.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Socket.io v2.1.1

So make sure you aren't accessing the sockets rooms in the `disconnect` event like I was, as they have already left the rooms by the time that event is triggered. If you want to do that try it in the `disconnecting` event - https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/pull/2332/files

Then you can use any of the following:

```
Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms)
Object.keys(socket.adapter.sids)
Object.keys(socket.rooms)
```

Comment: Using this method, is there a way to look up rooms that a socket is in by a `socket.id` string?  ie not using the `socket` that is passed to an event, but just a string containing `socket.id`?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0.3

```
io.sockets.sockets[yourSocketID].rooms
```

That equal with

```
socket.rooms
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.io **1.7.3 +**

```
var currentRoom = socket.rooms[Object.keys(socket.rooms)[0]];//returns name of room
```

Comment: `Object.keys` is not sorted, is it? I do not think this solution works in general.

Comment: to be honest I haven't tried it yet on more than one socket

Comment: that shows the socket id itself when we're trying to show the room

Answer (score 0):

You can save room in socket itself when it joins a room

```
// join room
socket.join(room);

// update socket's rooms
if (socket.rooms) {
    socket.rooms.push(room);
} else {
    socket.rooms = [room];
}
```

Later you can retrieve all rooms that the socket is in by simply

```
socket.rooms
```

From the Server API documentation:

> **socket.rooms** *(object)*
>   A hash of strings identifying the rooms this client is in, indexed by room name.

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-rooms

Comment: Just wondering, wouldn't `socket.rooms` be updated automatically by `socket.io` every time a socket joined a room?

Comment: in no way should you be modifying the API like this. why would you need to update socket.rooms when the library already does this?

Answer (score 0):

With `socket.rooms` you will get a set of socketId and its rooms.

So you can convert it into array and then slice it to get only the rooms  like this:

```
[...socket.rooms].slice(1, );
```

And then we can iterate through that array or access any room, for example:

```
[...socket.rooms].slice(1, )[1] // to get first room
```