# With socketio is it possible to use async with socket.on

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, promise

Is it possible to do something like that with socket io :

```
socket.on('event.here', async (data) => {
     const result:any = await webservice();
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to do it ?

Comment: Events are already asynchronous...

Comment: yes but you can't use await without specifying async on the function

Comment: Why are you calling a webservice at the moment an event happens? Perhaps you could decouple those two processes?

Comment: If you're using Typescript and getting eslint @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises just ignore it.  As of today the types for socket.io aren't strictly correct.  Socket.on() can handle a Promise<void> function just fine.

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can do it, but it depends on what you want to do. If you want to be able to await for some async operation inside callback than you are all set. But if you want for the next event to not fire before handling of previous one was finished than it won't work that way.

Here is a little simulation:

```
let socket = {
  listeners: [],
  on: function(name, callback) {
    if (!this.listeners[name]) {
      this.listeners[name] = [];
    }
    this.listeners[name].push(callback);
  },
  emit: function(name, data) {
    if (this.listeners[name]) {
        this.callListeners(this.listeners[name], data);
    }
  },
  callListeners: function(listeners, data) {
    listeners.shift()(data);
      if (listeners.length) {
        this.callListeners(listeners, data);
      }
  }
}

function returnsPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
  })
}

socket.on('event.here', async (data) => {
     const result = await returnsPromise();
     console.log('after await');
});

socket.on('event.here', async (data) => {
     const result = await returnsPromise();
     console.log('after await1');
});

socket.emit('event.here', {});
```

You can play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8qvg50u/2/) to get a feeling, in fact SocketIO has nothing to do with it being able to work.

Comment: Sorry to bring up this thread. But have you seen the behavior of this? When we put socket.on('event', async(data)=> { ... }) the sockets will drop the user. I am not quite sure how can I solve this.