# how to get socket ids of all users in specific room

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, backend, web-development-server

I want to get all user socket ids in room using room name.

i have tried below code but it didnt worked.

```
io.in(room).clients((err , clients) => {
    // must have got clients  array of socket ids , currently available in given room
});
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093638/socket-io-rooms-get-list-of-clients-in-specific-room) might help.

Comment: what is your socket.io version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket IO Rooms: Get list of clients in specific room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093638/socket-io-rooms-get-list-of-clients-in-specific-room)

Comment: @RidhamTarpara version is 4.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchSockets` will return all the socket instances

```
const sockets = await io.in(roomName).fetchSockets();
const socketIds = sockets.map(socket => socket.id);
```