# Get Connected Socket Socket.io & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am just trying to get connected sockets for a user list without other rooms, because i only have one room, which i want to get all connected users in the list. I am using NodeJS and socket.io.

This is not working:

```
var clients = io.sockets.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var clients = io.sockets.clients();` gives all the connected sockets. For socket.io 1.0+ see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145381/583363) answer.

Comment: That doesn't work anymore after the update of socket.io.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. This works fine of your last link that you gave, but my last question is, how can i get usernames in that room into the client?