# Sending notification using node.js + socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, push-notification, socket.io

I am trying to send notification using Node.js + soket.io

On client side i emit to server to listen

```
socket.emit('send to server',{user_id:user_id,other_stuff:other_stuff})
```

On node

```
socket.on('send to server',function(date){ socket.emit('notification_'+user_id,'test data'); });
```

On client side to listen notification

```
socket.on("notification_<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>",function(date){alert(data)});
```

Problem is that it doesn't send notification to other user

If i pass my own user_id during emit "send to server" then it returns to myself but if use other user_id (who is logged in other borwser) it doesn't send anything to that user.

Please point how i can send notification to different user when some action occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you want to send a notification to other users under the same namespace:

```
socket.on('send to server',function(data){ 
        socket.broadcast('notification','test data'); 
    })
```

only for a specific user (sockets.io 1.x)

```
socket.on('send to server',function(data){ 
    socketId =  getSocketIdFromUserId(user_id);
    io.to(socketId).emit('notification', 'test data');
 })
```

there's no need to join the id with the name of your listener
on the client side:

```
socket.on('notification',function(data){
    alert(data)
});
```

Comment: Hello Jack, thanks a lot for your answer, just had one little doubt, when i will  use io.to(data.user_id), who node will identify which user to send

Comment: my mistake is the socketId that you'll need to pass

Comment: you probably will need to do a map between the socketId and the userId, take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients

Comment: Jack can you help me out with one more problem

Comment: Sure open another question and tag me

Comment: thanks jack, i figured was problem with my host as i was using shared hosting