# Internal socket.io clients list location

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am wondering if Socket.io will *internally* do bookkeeping and allow the user to retrieve a list of clients, or if we will *manually* need to keep track of a list of connected clients like so:

```
var Server = require('socket.io');
var io = new Server(3980, {});

const clients = [];

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    clients.push(socket);

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {

        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket),1);

    });
});
```

does socket.io store a list of connections, somewhere like:

```
io.connections
```

or

```
io.sockets
```

having more trouble than I expected to find this information, for newer versions of socket.io. I am using  version =>  `"socket.io": "^1.7.2"`

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients

Answer (score 4):

The following function will give you an array of socket objects:

```
function clients(namespace) {
    var res = [];
    var ns = io.of(namespace || "/");
    if (ns) {
        Object.keys(ns.connected).forEach(function (id) {
                res.push(ns.connected[id]);
        });
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need this: **io.sockets.connected**

```
var clients = Object.keys(io.sockets.connected);
```

then if you need a socket:

`var socket = io.sockets.connected[socket_id]`

Comment: that might be it, will test it out - but to be specific I need the socket connection objects, not the ids, so maybe it's Object.values(io.sockets.connected)?

Comment: then io.sockets.connected[socket_id]