# Socket.io 2.0.4 - Loop through all connected sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hello I'm trying to loop through all connected sockets and check if they have the session data (userid) I'm looking for. Here's my code (doesn't work):

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients();
console.log(clients);

for(i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    if(clients[i].handshake.session.userid == userid) {
        clients[i].emit(event, data);
    }
}
```

My question is how I could find an array of sockets since io.sockets.clients() doesn't seem to return an array with the socket objects.

Comment: Define `doesn't work`

Comment: io.sockets.clients().connected doesn't return an array of sockets and therefor I find it hard to loop through all the connected sockets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.IO - how do I get a list of connected sockets/clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients)

Comment: Ty, will try that later, but it says socket.io 0.7 you have the clients method

Comment: That is what I have in my code that I posted. (io.sockets.clients())

Comment: It doesn't give me an error but it doesn't emit anything either when I use the function. Not a duplicate since I got no working answer.

Comment: You're not using v0.7, you said you're using 2.0.4. So it should be `io.sockets.sockets`. And yes it's a duplicate

Comment: I found the answer in this article but not the marked answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145381/9332886

Comment: Yes. I never said the first answer was the one you needed. There are 27 answers to this question

Comment: Yes sorry it was my bad, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

```
var sockets = io.sockets.sockets;
for(var socketId in sockets) {
          var s = sockets[socketId]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.io@2.3.0

`io.sockets.sockets` is an object where a key is a `socketId` and value is reference to the socket object.

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((socketId) => {
  const socket = io.sockets.sockets[socketId];
})
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work in ^4